# pull access denied for oracle/serverjre

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have been trying to build a docker image for oracle/weblogic 12.2.1.

I followed all the instructions carefully as given in the official repo.

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.1

but when i run:

```
docker build -t oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.1-developer .
```

it gives me a permission denied error.

---

```
sudo docker build -t oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.1-developer .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  54.79MB

Step 1/13 : FROM oracle/serverjre:8

pull access denied for oracle/serverjre, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

---

can anyone please help me??

Thankyou

Comment: This seems like something you should be raising with Bruno on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by having a docker image built for oracle/serverjre:8 in my machine.

I downloaded the oracle/Serverjre8 binaries and built a docker image then built the weblogic.And it worked !!

Alternately,you can pull the image for Oracle/ServerJre8 directly from Oracle container registry or Docker store by logging in first.

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
Username: <oracle sso="" username="">
Password: <oracle sso="" password="">
Login successful.
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
```

Answer (score 6):

For some time now, it's needed not only to login with the Oracle account, but also to accept the license and user agreement. So you cannot do it only from command line. You must go to the Oracle container registry:

https://container-registry.oracle.com/

Then select `Java` repository, then select `serverjre`, then signin:

[image]

And accept the license:

[image]

Once you have done that, you'll be able to pull the docker image, but as other have said, you'll need to change the registry that is set inside the Dockerfile:

```
#FROM oracle/serverjre:8
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
```

And afterwards, before running the build, you must do a `docker login`

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
username:<SSO USERNAME>
password:<SSO PASSWORD>
```

At this point, you'll be able to pull the image.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the pattern used in the git hub project https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/

If you checkout the project and go into the OracleJava directory and look at the *.download file (in this case for JRE 8: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleJava/java-8/server-jre-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz.download)

There is a link to download the tarball (after you accept the license agreement and sign in).

You can then place the tarball in the same directory as the build.sh (OracleJava/java-8).

Run: **sh build.sh**

This should then create the docker image of oracle/serverjre:8

You can should then be able to do your build and the instance of the image will be found locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom image with Dockerfile, Delete the `oracle/` it's not your local repository.
Try `docker build -t weblogic:12.2.1.1-developer .`
Or just make a `docker run [image]`

Comment: im not using a custom image

Comment: so you can't use 'docker build .' without dockerfile, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Considering WebLogic version 12.2.1.3, In case of PULL error and changing the registry to oracle registry, Below conditions should be checked-

While executing the script buildDockerImage.sh, make sure Dockerfile.developer (/docker-images/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3/Dockerfile.developer) has entry to be changed-

```
#FROM oracle/serverjre:8
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
```

User might need to be logged at oracle container registry for pull operation, so better is to login first prior to script execution.

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
username:<SSO USERNAME>
password:<SSO PASSWORD>
```

Also /docker-images/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3/ contains **fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip.download** file, that indicates necessary physical download of **fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip** to be done from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-for-dev-1703574.html and the same should be available at /docker-images/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you created the Java image from OracleJava/8 you use the parameter version: 8-slim and with that image you try to create the weblogic image.

You just should use the version for default : Oracle Server JRE 8 on Oracle Linux 7 slim when create the OraclaJava image
[build.sh for Oracle Java images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAF4m.png)

With that image of Java, you can create your weblogic image without problems, because that java image has tag: oracle/serverjre:8

```
echo "Building Oracle Server JRE 8 on Oracle Linux 7 slim"
docker build --tag oracle/serverjre:8 --tag oracle/serverjre:8-oraclelinux7 .
```